Dont have sound on my hp envy 15, apparmour errors with pulseaudio
I have trouble with sound on my hp, speakers dont work but headphones do, and i saw all other threads about this problem. None of the solutions helped, but i dug up this message and I guess that is the problem in my case.
13:37:11 ig0r-hp-envy-x360 kernel: [   42.658680] kauditd_printk_skb: 98 callbacks suppressed
May  3 13:37:11 ig0r-hp-envy-x360 kernel: [   42.658684] audit: type=1400 audit(1714736231.214:899): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap.pulseaudio>
May  3 13:37:11 ig0r-hp-envy-x360 kernel: [   42.659032] audit: type=1400 audit(1714736231.214:900): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap.pulseaudio>
May  3 13:37:11 ig0r-hp-envy-x360 kernel: [   42.659372] audit: type=1400 audit(1714736231.214:901): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap.pulseaudio>
May  3 13:37:11 ig0r-hp-envy-x360 kernel: [   42.659708] audit: type=1400 audit(1714736231.214:902): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap.pulseaudio>
May  3 13:37:11 ig0r-hp-envy-x360 kernel: [   42.660038] audit: type=1400 audit(1714736231.214:903): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap.pulseaudio>
May  3 13:37:11 ig0r-hp-envy-x360 kernel: [   42.660367] audit: type=1400 audit(1714736231.214:904): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap.pulseaudio>
May  3 13:37:11 ig0r-hp-envy-x360 kernel: [   42.660732] audit: type=1400 audit(1714736231.218:905): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap.pulseaudio>
May  3 13:37:11 ig0r-hp-envy-x360 kernel: [   42.661061] audit: type=1400 audit(1714736231.218:906): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap.pulseaudio>
May  3 13:37:11 ig0r-hp-envy-x360 kernel: [   42.661389] audit: type=1400 audit(1714736231.218:907): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap.pulseaudio>
May  3 13:37:11 ig0r-hp-envy-x360 kernel: [   42.661721] audit: type=1400 audit(1714736231.218:908): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap.pulseaudio>
May  3 13:37:11 ig0r-hp-envy-x360 pulseaudio.pulseaudio[1017]: E: [pulseaudio] module-alsa-card.c: Failed to find a working profile.
May  3 13:37:11 ig0r-hp-envy-x360 pulseaudio.pulseaudio[1017]: E: [pulseaudio] module.c: Failed to load module "module-alsa-card" (argument: "device_id="2" name="pci-0000_04>
May  3 13:37:12 ig0r-hp-envy-x360 systemd[1]: fprintd.service: Deactivated successfully.
May  3 13:37:17 ig0r-hp-envy-x360 systemd[1]: pulseaudio.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 4.
May  3 13:37:17 ig0r-hp-envy-x360 systemd[1]: Stopped PulseAudio Sound Server.
May  3 13:37:17 ig0r-hp-envy-x360 systemd[1]: Started PulseAudio Sound Server.
May  3 13:37:17 ig0r-hp-envy-x360 systemd[3416]: pulseaudio.service: Failed to determine user credentials: No such process
May  3 13:37:17 ig0r-hp-envy-x360 systemd[3416]: pulseaudio.service: Failed at step USER spawning /usr/bin/pulseaudio: No such process
May  3 13:37:17 ig0r-hp-envy-x360 systemd[1]: pulseaudio.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=217/USER
May  3 13:37:17 ig0r-hp-envy-x360 systemd[1]: pulseaudio.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
May  3 13:37:18 ig0r-hp-envy-x360 kernel: [   49.597283] kauditd_printk_skb: 41 callbacks suppressed

I have looked around, but i really dont know what to do about apparmor, i just heard of it.
please help, if you need any other info from me, I can give you.
EDIT
After I disabled apparmor and tried starting pulseaudio, I got the error: Failed at step USER spawning /usr/bin/pulseaudio: No such process
Then I changed pulseaudio.service file, I set user to the name of my user, and I set group to nogroup.
Now I get these errors:
May  3 15:51:58 ig0r-hp-envy-x360 pulseaudio.pulseaudio[1002]: E: [pulseaudio] module-alsa-card.c: Failed to find a working profile.
May  3 15:51:58 ig0r-hp-envy-x360 pulseaudio.pulseaudio[1002]: E: [pulseaudio] module.c: Failed to load module "module-alsa-card" (argument: "device_id="2" name="pci-0000_04_00.5-platform-acp_pdm_mach.0">
May  3 15:52:08 ig0r-hp-envy-x360 systemd[1]: pulseaudio.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 10.
May  3 15:52:08 ig0r-hp-envy-x360 systemd[1]: Stopped PulseAudio Sound Server.
May  3 15:52:08 ig0r-hp-envy-x360 systemd[1]: Started PulseAudio Sound Server.
May  3 15:52:09 ig0r-hp-envy-x360 rtkit-daemon[799]: Supervising 7 threads of 3 processes of 1 users.
May  3 15:52:09 ig0r-hp-envy-x360 rtkit-daemon[799]: message repeated 4 times: [ Supervising 7 threads of 3 processes of 1 users.]
May  3 15:52:09 ig0r-hp-envy-x360 pulseaudio[3513]: Unable to contact D-Bus: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NotSupported: Unable to autolaunch a dbus-daemon without a $DISPLAY for X11
May  3 15:52:09 ig0r-hp-envy-x360 pulseaudio[3513]: Unable to contact D-Bus: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NotSupported: Unable to autolaunch a dbus-daemon without a $DISPLAY for X11
May  3 15:52:09 ig0r-hp-envy-x360 systemd[1]: pulseaudio.service: Deactivated successfully.




Try the command sudo sysctl -w kernel.apparmor_restrict_unprivileged_userns=0 to temporarily disable apparmor until you reboot. Try restarting the pulseaudio service. Does that work?

@ArchismanPanigrahi Thank you for your response. I still have no audio, but I edited the post with some new info
